# int32_t main() vs int main()

Tags: c++, signature, int32

I've written a cpp program, and I am able to run it with `int32_t main()` but not with the signature `int main()`.

Can someone tell me why? Its a .cpp file and not a .c file (as mentioned in some other questions).

Comment: Sounds very strange. Could you post the source code?

Comment: Does it happen also for `int32_t main() {}` vs `int main() {}`? I mean, with an empty `main`.

Comment: Please show a [mre] and add some details about how you are not able to run it. Does that mean it doesn't compile?

Comment: [`int32_t main() {}`](https://onlinegdb.com/H1cNf-bXP) & [`int main()`](https://onlinegdb.com/Syv8GWbXv) both seems to be working fine on OnlineGDB. You need to add more information to your question by editing it.

Comment: Which compiler? Platform? What was the error message? etc.

Comment: Apparently it had a weird ```#define int``` statement in an included file which was causing this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The possible explanation could be that one of your `#include` files at the top redefines `int` as something else. This may happen if somebody tried to change the data type in some algorithm by simply redefining `int`.

Try to put `#undef int` into a line line immediately before the `int main()` to restore the default meaning of "int".

Comment: Yes, that's the workaround if this abomination is actually what's happening. But it's important to underscore that this situation should never be allowed to arise. +1.

Comment: So can be said about any bug.

Comment: Redefining a keyword is not "any bug". There's no good reason to do that, and it makes code unreadable. Not to mention introducing undefined behavior into any but the most trivial programs.